# OpenNMS recognizes traps as uei.opennms.org/generic/traps/EnterpriseDefault

Tags: opennms

OpenNMS is receiving the following traps from a F5 load balancer:

```
uei.opennms.org/generic/traps/EnterpriseDefault
Received unformatted enterprise event (enterprise:.1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4 generic:6 specific:131). 2 args: .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4.1.1="Pool member 10.4.7.72:0 exceeded configured rate limit." .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0=".1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4"

<event>
  <mask>
     <maskelement>
        <mename>id</mename>
        <mevalue>.1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4</mevalue>
     </maskelement>
     <maskelement>
        <mename>generic</mename>
        <mevalue>6</mevalue>
     </maskelement>
     <maskelement>
        <mename>specific</mename>
        <mevalue>131</mevalue>
     </maskelement>
  </mask>
  <uei>uei.opennms.org/traps/F5-BIGIP-COMMON-MIB/bigipMemberRate</uei>
  <event-label>F5-BIGIP-COMMON-MIB defined trap event: bigipMemberRate</event-label>
  <descr>&lt;p>A pool member has exceeded the allowed rate.&lt;/p>&lt;table>
    &lt;tr>&lt;td>&lt;b>

    bigipNotifyObjMsg&lt;/b>&lt;/td>&lt;td>
    %parm[#1]%;&lt;/td>&lt;td>&lt;p>&lt;/p>&lt;/td>&lt;/tr>&lt;/table>
    </descr>
  <logmsg dest="logndisplay">&lt;p>
    bigipMemberRate trap received
    bigipNotifyObjMsg=%parm[#1]%&lt;/p>
    </logmsg>
  <severity>Major</severity>
</event>
```

The above is from "/opt/opennms/etc/events# less F5-BIGIP-COMMON-MIB.events.xml", which is already defined in "eventconf.xml":

```
pd11scl-nms-w01:/opt/opennms/etc# grep F5 eventconf.xml
   <event-file>events/F5-BIGIP-COMMON-MIB.events.xml</event-file>
   <event-file>events/F5.events.xml</event-file>
pd11scl-nms-w01:/opt/opennms/etc#
```

I have restarted OpenNMS multiple times, but still the traps are not recognized as a F5 one.

Any thoughts?  Any quick suggestion is greatly appreciated as we have been struggling that for quite some time and not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the events tag around the event tag in the clip above.